# Jest Enzyme impossible to locate imported function in mount()

Tags: typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have to mount a component that uses a function from library. The function is used in the componentDidMount cycle. Everything looks somewhat like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.slider = null;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setupValues();
    }
    setupValues() {
        this.slider = {
            ...,
            format: dayjs(val).format(...)
        }
    }
    render() {...}
}
```

Now the wrapper that I am trying to use in my test is:

```
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
    ...
```

Sadly, the test does not even run because the mount function fails saying: `dayjs is not a function`

Why does it fail to find the imported dayjs function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dayjs` function is the [`default` export of the module](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/c4517a86e64bcb9edee35234f7484db01b7ba16e/src/index.js#L405).

That means you need to [import it like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export):

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
```

Comment: I use typescript thus it is exported not as default: https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/c4517a86e64bcb9edee35234f7484db01b7ba16e/index.d.ts

Comment: Seems like the issue was in the test environment configurations. Your answers is correct from one perspective.